# In north America is their mammals that can survive from falling from hundreds of feet?

Tags: zoology, mammals

Like animals have great attributes but is their any mammals that have unique attributes to survive such fate of death?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few, including *[Corynorhinus townsendii virginianus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corynorhinus_townsendii_virginianus)*, *[Eptesicus fuscus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eptesicus_fuscus)*, and [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bats_of_the_United_States).

[image]

Comment: No I’m asking about resilience animals to surrive such fate

Comment: Like surviving falls. That can kill people but mammals are munch stronger then human so they have more of chance of survival